# Numerical argument is out of domain: Ruby

Tags: ruby

Not entirely sure how to write out my expression correctly but my task is "Given an integral number, determine if it's a square number:"

Example:

```
-1  =>  false
 0  =>  true
 3  =>  false
 4  =>  true
25  =>  true
26  =>  false
```

My code:

```
def is_square(x)
  Math.sqrt(x).to_r.denominator == 1
end
```

Output:

Fails on the following: ****should work for some examples****

```
 #<Math::DomainError: Numerical argument is out of domain - "sqrt">
 main.rb:5:in `sqrt'
 main.rb:5:in `is_square'
 main.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

Passes the following two:
should work for random square numbers (100 of 100 Assertions)
should work for random numbers (100 of 100 Assertions)

Comment: Given that, try use `abs`: `Math.sqrt(x.abs).to_r.denominator == 1`. But for `x = -1` is `true` (`true` for negative squares). So maybe better: `x > 0 && Math.sqrt(x).to_r.denominator == 1`

Comment: thanks mate ```x > 0 && Math.sqrt(x).to_r.denominator == 1``` worked. I made a minor adjustment to pass all the test by doing ```x > -1``` though.

Comment: It all boils down to what is meant by, "...determine if it [a given integer] is a square number". If that means, "...determine if it is equal to the square of a number", I would say that `Math.sqrt(x.abs).to_r.denominator ==1` is correct, as complex numbers are numbers. (If `x` is a negative integer `0` and `Math.sqrt(-x)` are the real and maginary parts of the square root of `x`.) If Ruby terms, if we regard numbers as elements of `Numeric` or one of its subclasses then complex numbers are numbers since `Complex` is a subclass of `Numeric`.

Comment: Though not directly relevant to this question, the module `Math` has a counterpoint module [CMath](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/cmath/rdoc/CMath.html) (`require 'cmath'` needed) containing methods for use with complex numbers. Real and imaginary parts can be extracted with [Complex#real](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Complex.html#method-i-real) and [Comple#imaginary](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Complex.html#method-i-imaginary) (a.k.a Complex#imag).

Answer (score 2):

As [the documentation says](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Math.html#method-c-sqrt), the domain of `Math::sqrt` is [0, ∞). You cannot pass a negative number as an argument.

Comment: You cannot pass a negative argument? `Math::sqrt(n) rescue nil`.

Answer (score 0):

The square root of a negative number is a complex number, which is out of the domain of the function `Math::sqrt` (only rational and irrational numbers, I suppose). You might have to implement that logic on your own or find a library that does that.